# How can I enforce an invariant of two variables' truthiness and their relationship to each other in a logical or?

Tags: typescript, types

In the following code block, it's logically sound that `x` is a `string`:

```
function sample(one: boolean, two?: string) {
  if (one || two) {
    const x: string = one ? 'hello' : two;
    // Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
  }
}
```

Typescript rejects this as it cannot infer that if `one` *or* `two` is truthy, then `x` will always evaluate to a string.

Without casting, is there a way to express the relationship of `one` and `two` to the type system such that Typescript can verify this the validity of this program?

Comment: TS doesn't try to solve arbitrary boolean satisfiability problems. See [ms/TS#54252](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54252). You should either just assert (what you call "casting") or refactor to something it can follow like `const x = one || two || "hello"`. Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The link you provided is certainly helpful, however I realized that my minimal reproduction of the issue is slightly incorrect. `one` should be a `boolean` not a `string`, and so the `one || two || "hello"` solution won't work for my use case. Let me edit the question to reflect this. Do you happen to have any suggestions for type-safe refactors in this scenario?

Comment: Like `const x: string = one ? "hello" : two || "";` then?  But that's kind of up to you; the main point is that you can't get the compiler to follow your logic so you'll either need to assert or refactor to something that might be redundant.  Shall I write up an answer or am I still missing something?

Comment: Yes you can write up an answer, it sounds like the conclusion is that this can't be expressed purely with types.

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance; might not be for a number of hours.

Comment: Sounds good. If you have a suggestion for a better title, do tell. I struggled to succinctly describe the issue, and I don't think what I came up with is the clearest.

Comment: Your title is fine, by the way.  Or at least I can't easily improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's ability to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) expressions based on [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) is generally limited to direct local testing like `typeof x === "string"` will narrow `x` to `string`.

It mostly does not try to keep track of how one expression affects another expression, or how a later test could interact with the results of an earlier test.  The compiler cannot spend the resources to simulate every possible way of running the program by hypothetically narrowing every [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) to each member (e.g., analyze the body of `sample` four times, for each of the joint truthiness states of `one` and `two`), and it is not able to reason abstractly about counterfactual events (e.g., "if I'm in a block where `one || two` is truthy and I then learn that `two` is falsy then `one` cannot also be falsy because otherwise I wouldn't be in this block").

This is a general limitation of TypeScript, as discussed in various GitHub issues such as [microsoft/TypeScript#54252](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/54252) (which links to other relevant issues).  Indeed the general class of such logical analysis, [the Boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), is only known to be solvable in a time that grows exponentially in size of the problem.  Of course it might be possible to do better in the specific case of two variables like `one` and `two`, there would very quickly be diminishing returns for situations involving more variables, so this hasn't really been explored much.

---

If you find yourself writing code that works this way, it might be worthwhile trying to refactor so that the tests are done more "directly", which might involve some more redundancy than you'd like. The best way to do this depends strongly on your use cases.  Maybe something like this would work for your example:

```
function sample(one: boolean, two?: string) {
  const x = one ? "hello" : two;
  if (x) {
    // whatever you wanted to do
  }
}
```

Or maybe this:

```
function sample(one: boolean, two?: string) {
  if (one) {
    doSomethingWithX("hello");
  } else if (two) {
    doSomethingWithX(two);
  }

  function doSomethingWithX(x: string) {
    // whatever you wanted to do
  }
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYFsAOAbApgCgVwC5EAjOOPVMAGkSgHc4B+U5KAJxjAHMBKRAG8AUCMSIICDogAeiALyIiiFogBEAC1zZscdYlJM4AbnGIYwRPlmDREiQHpHiRptRRcAN1ydEATzgQVxpPABMGOEQwuHMAXzEEkVBIWAQUDBxcACZCMBJySmo6BmY2FC4eAWExCUtrIjtzCRiAZTh0XChNKoB1GG6ADXwtHT11fjMJOMQdZFwLK3xjJodouHbO7r6BzWGVqcQkiRToeCQ2jq6evn6hm3ZKvlWHZ1d3Tx8-QODGUNwIlAojF4okgA)